# Reset form fields after clicking on Submit Button

Tags: javascript

I have tried other helpful comments but still can not get my code to work. I am new to js so I really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks you.

// Form submit

```
$(".feedback-form").submit(function(e){
    $('.message', this).remove();
    if($(".feedback-form").valid()){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prepend('<div class="loading"></div>');
        dataString = $(".feedback-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.feedback-form .loading').remove();
                $('.feedback-form').prepend('<div class="message message-ok">Sent successfully!</div>').find('.message').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                $('feedback-form')[0].reset();
```

Comment: so now what is happening?

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your success function:

```
$(".feedback-form").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot "." in selector

```
$('feedback-form')[0].reset();
```

Correct it to:

```
$('.feedback-form')[0].reset();
```

So, check if this can help you.

Else, other options using jquery and javascript:

```
$('.feedback-form').trigger("reset");

$(".feedback-form").get(0).reset();

document.getElementsByClassName('feedback-form').reset();
```

And using input type `reset`:

```
<input type="reset">
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the "." but still was not working.